# Why is memory address the same after pointing at new Object?

Tags: swift, class, reference-type

I have the following set up in a playground and am expecting the last two memory address to be the same. I point `person2` to `person1` then `person1` is reassigned to a new Person so `person2` should have the same memory address as person1.

Why does it have the same address as to when we first assign it?

```
class Person {
  var name = ""
}

var person1 = Person()
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(person1).toOpaque())
//0x0000600000043ea0

var person2 = person1

person1 = Person()
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(person1).toOpaque())
//0x00006000000568f0
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(person2).toOpaque())
//0x0000600000043ea0
```

Comment: Because you did not change `person2` ?  The thing to remember here is that variables like person1 and person2 here are "object references" - the two variables contain references to some object.  So, `person1 = new Person()` sets person1 to be a reference to some new Person object.  `person2 = person1` sets person2 to have another reference to same person object - now you have two references to the same object.  `person1 = new Person()` changes person1 so it is now a reference to a new object - but leaves person2 unchanged.

Comment: I would have thought if you point object 2 at object 1, object 2 would continue to point at object 1 even if object 1's memory address changes, seems like this assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe that's the misunderstanding - from your POV as a programmer, an object never changes memory address.  The first person created, when you first assign a reference to it in person1, is placed somewhere in memory and never moves, and person1 gets a reference to it.  person1 is not the object, just a reference to it. person2 then gets another reference to the same object.  Then a second object is created elsewhere in memory, and person 1 changes its value so that it now is/has a reference to this second object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how reference types work in Swift.

When you've created `person1` it's an instance of the class `Person`. `person1` is then a pointer/reference to a place in the memory that represents that instance.

Then you instantiate `var person2 = person1`, so `person2` becomes another pointer to the same location in the memory. But they are two different/independant pointers.

The line `person1 = Person()` changes the location in memory to which `person1` points: a new instance of the class `Person`. You haven't updated the instance to which `person2` points.

Comment: Another detail is that "class Person" makes it a reference type, where "struct Person" would make it a value type.  Of course, neither of those would act like the asker expects...

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a table that tracks the objects `person1` and `person2` point to, as the code progresses:

```
// code                   | person1 points to: | person2 points to: 
// -----------------------+--------------------+--------------------
// start                  | 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
var person1 = Person() // | 0x0000600000043ea0 | 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
let person2 = person1  // | 0x0000600000043ea0 | 0x0000600000043ea0
person1 = Person()     // | 0x00006000000568f0 | 0x0000600000043ea0
```

The `X`s represent uninitialized memory, which could have any value (from whatever was stored there before).

`person1` and `person2` are variables, which are stored on the stack, whose contents are the addresses of (references to) `Person` objects. For clarity's sake, let's give the `Person` objects names:

- Person Object `X`, at 0x0000600000043ea0
- Person Object `Y`, at 0x00006000000568f0

[image: Object graph showing reference type aliasing.]

Comment: There is a typo in your image. It should be person1 = Person() in the last section instead of person2 =....

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ah yes, indeed. But I don't have the time to fix it D: